# Android app setting for 24hr time

Tags: java, android, draw, android-preferences

I'm trying to add the option in my app for 24hr (international) time. Currently the time is drawn for BottomLabel and TopLabel in 12hr (AM/PM) mode. I've added this option to the settings menu, but now need to implement it when the Preference is selected. How???

I think I need an if-statement to check for the Prefence, but I'm unsure; see `WHAT GOES HERE???` in the code. Below is what should be the relevant code. Thank you in advance for your help!

In preferences.xml:

```
<PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/pref_other_category">
    <ListPreference
        android:title="@string/pref_hour_category"
        android:defaultValue="h"
        android:entries="@array/arr_hr_type_entries"
        android:entryValues="@array/arr_data_refresh_rate_values"
        android:key="hour_format" />
</PreferenceCategory>
```

And where I convert the time format and draw the labels in TimeSliderView.java:

```
/**
 * Get the current aggregation type based on the date range
 */
@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
public void setAggregation(AggregationType aggregation) {
    _aggregation = aggregation;
    // Update date format symbols converting "AM/PM" to "a/p"
    DateFormatSymbols symbols = new DateFormatSymbols(Locale.US);
    symbols.setAmPmStrings(new String[]{"a", "p"});
    // Configure date formatter based on new aggregation type
    switch (_aggregation) {
        case Hour:
            _sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm", symbols);
            break;
        case HalfDay:
            _sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mma", symbols);
            break;
        case Day:
            if (WHAT GOES HERE???) {
                _sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("Ha", symbols);
            } else{
                _sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("ha", symbols);
            }
            break;
        case Week:
            _sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("E", symbols);
            break;
    }
    invalidate();
}

/**
 * Draw the given time at the given position
 *
 * @param canvas the canvas on which the background will be drawn
 * @param time   The timestamp in milliseconds to draw
 */
private void drawLabel(Canvas canvas, long time, float left, float top, float right,
        float bottom) {

    if (_showBottomLabel || _showTopLabel) {
        _calendar.setTimeInMillis(time);
        String labelStr = _sdf.format(_calendar.getTime());
        _labelRect.set(left, top, right, bottom);
        // Draw  top label
        if (_showTopLabel) {
            canvas.drawText(labelStr, _labelRect.left, _labelRect.top + _labelCenterTop,
                    _textPaint);
        }
        // Draw  bottom label
        if (_showBottomLabel) {
            canvas.drawText(labelStr, _labelRect.left, _labelRect.bottom - _labelCenterBottom,
                    _textPaint);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Draw labels top and bottom background on the given canvas
 */
private void drawLabelsBackground(Canvas canvas, long time, float left, float top, float right,
        float bottom) {

    if (_showBottomLabel || _showTopLabel) {
        // Check for next bar therefore add one interval to time
        boolean isClosed = !TaurusApplication.getMarketCalendar().isOpen(new Date(time + DataUtils.METRIC_DATA_INTERVAL));
        if (_showBottomLabel) {
            _labelRect.set(left, bottom - _labelHeight, right, top + getHeight());
            canvas.drawRect(_labelRect, isClosed ? _darkPaint : _lightPaint);
            // Draw label divider lines
            if (!_collapsed || !isClosed) {
                _labelRect.bottom = _labelRect.top + 1;
                canvas.drawRect(_labelRect, _strokePaint);
            }
        }
        if (_showTopLabel) {
            _labelRect.set(left, top, right, top + _labelHeight);
            canvas.drawRect(_labelRect, isClosed ? _darkPaint : _lightPaint);
            // Draw label divider lines
            if (!_collapsed || !isClosed) {
                _labelRect.top = _labelRect.bottom - 1;
                canvas.drawRect(_labelRect, _strokePaint);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android setting for 24 hr time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28159004/android-setting-for-24-hr-time)

Comment: @tyczj just a redo of the question to be more clear :)
Deleted the original.

Comment: Do you really need to build that yourself or wouldn't it be easier to just rely on the current user's locale settings and use [DateUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html) instead?

Comment: @MichelJung I would like the user to have the option of changing this setting, independent of where they are.